# how to draw google map rectangle if I only know its size and northeast point

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

to draw a rectangle in google map, I need to know northwest and southeast points to construct a LatLngbounds first.

In my situation, I want to draw a rectangle with specific northwest point and a size (say 100 meters width and 100 meters height). I do not know the southest point.

I am afraid of geometry and geology. I know the southeast can be derived from some fomulas. Just want to know whether there is api or easy ways to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write a function like this:

```
// Given the LatLng of a northwest corner, and the number of meters to
// measure east and south, return the LatLngBounds for that rectangle
function makeBounds( nw, metersEast, metersSouth ) {
    var ne = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(
        nw, metersEast, 90
    );
    var sw = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(
        nw, metersSouth, 180
    );
    return new google.maps.LatLngBounds( sw, ne );
}
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/geary/6cCvG/2/).

Answer (score 1):

See [computeOffset](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical) in the geometry library.

computeOffset(from:LatLng, distance:number, heading:number, radius?:number)

Something like (not tested):

```
var NorthEast = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(NorthWest, width, 90);
var SouthWest = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(NorthWest, height, 180);
var SouthEast = google.maps.LatLng(SouthWest.lat(),NorthEast.lng());
```

Be sure to include the [geometry library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/libraries)